# Codeigniter 4 include another parser to parser template view

Tags: php, view, codeigniter-4

I want create library to generate dynamic template using parser codeigniter 4.0.3 with inserting another parser as _content variable to template using parser. But the _content result just show html code. This is my library code :

```
if(!empty($template)){ //$template is path vdashboard.php
    $this->data['_content']=$this->parser->setData($this->data)->render($template);
}else{
    $this->data['_content']=null;
} 
echo $this->parser->setData($this->data)->render('templates/vtemplates');
```

And this is my template view to add content, i give filename vtemplate.php :

```
<div class="row layout-top-spacing">

    {_content}
                
</div>
```

Example, i want to load view with filename vdashboard.php and push it to vtemplate.php

```
<h2>{welcome}</h2>
```

The result is `<h2>Welcome</h2>`  not `Welcome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today i find the answer.
This is because parser CI 4 Escaping Data to help prevent XSS attacks. So, you must unscaping variable  __content

Just add ! between variable :

```
{__content}
```

To :

```
{!__content!}
```